# Android: Is there any enterprise certificate or key for android apk

Tags: android

I want to know that is there any key or certificate provided by google or google play services to any enterprise so that one can install that signed app without checking the "Unknown Resources" option. or without any popup regarding to non-market app.

Comment: Without checking I highly doubt that. It would just bypass every security measurement they have done with restricting installation from "unknown resources" etc.

Comment: No I dont think so any such certificates will be issued. Think it would be better to ask in [Google Developer forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Android-developers). Some one from Google team might respond back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google fully expects phone users to have to enable the ability to download from Unknown Sources as per the wording in [the documents about alternative distribution](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html).

> Android protects users from inadvertent download and install of apps
>   from locations other than Google Play (which is trusted). It blocks
>   such installs until the user opts-in Unknown sources in Settings >
>   Security, shown in Figure 2. Users need to make this configuration
>   change before they download your apps to their devices.